# BUILD FAILURE Error: when executing "mvn clean package" command

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm using following version.

- maven: 3.3.9
- jdk: java-7-openjdk-amd64
- JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"

I'm getting packages type error when I'm running $ mvn clean package command. I'm new to use swagger to generate documentation(.yml file to .html)

#### ERROR:

```
enter code here[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java:21:5: Missing a Javadoc comment. [JavadocMethod]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java:28: Line is longer than 100 characters (found 233). [LineLength]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java:35:5: Missing a Javadoc comment. [JavadocMethod]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java:37:27: Local variable name 'b' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [LocalVariableName]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java:46:36: Catch parameter name 'e' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [CatchParameterName]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/config/ConfigParser.java:10: Import statement for 'org.slf4j.Logger' is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE' group, expecting not assigned imports on this line. [CustomImportOrder]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/config/ConfigParser.java:11: Import statement for 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory' is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE' group, expecting not assigned imports on this line. [CustomImportOrder]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/config/ConfigParser.java:17:5: Missing a Javadoc comment. [JavadocMethod]
[WARN] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/config/ConfigParser.java:38:28: Catch parameter name 'e' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. [CatchParameterName]
Audit done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ swagger-codegen ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ swagger-codegen ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ swagger-codegen ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1563 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ swagger-codegen ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 147 source files to /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/examples/XmlExampleGenerator.java:[17,32] package org.codehaus.plexus.util does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] swagger-codegen-project ............................ SUCCESS [  2.958 s]
[INFO] swagger-codegen (core library) ..................... FAILURE [ 11.114 s]
[INFO] swagger-codegen (executable) ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] swagger-codegen (maven-plugin) ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] swagger-generator .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.646 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-16T15:36:08+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/553M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project swagger-codegen: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/examples/XmlExampleGenerator.java:[17,32] package org.codehaus.plexus.util does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :swagger-codegen
```

I've also run debugging mode by running mvn clean package -X, but nothing getting in mind please any one look into it save my life.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following line:

```
[ERROR] /var/www/html/cg-api-dev-portal/codegen/swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/examples/XmlExampleGenerator.java:[17,32] package org.codehaus.plexus.util does not exist
```

Looks like you're not using the latest master, which has the following line instead:

```
 16 import io.swagger.models.properties.AbstractNumericProperty;
 17 import io.swagger.models.properties.PasswordProperty;
 18 import io.swagger.models.properties.UUIDProperty;
```

Please clone from the latest master.

You can also use the SNAPSHOT version without building the project manually:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#compatibility

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed my repository on swagger-codegen 2.2.3 but error remain same.

Comment: I've rechecked, all these latest models are exist in XmlExampleGenerator.java file..

Comment: Instead of doing another check, I would suggest you to clone the swagger codegen again in another folder.

Comment: Yes friend I did it but result is same

Comment: I would suggest you to use another machine (home, work) to try again